# python selenium find text of child of previous parent

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I have the following document:

```
<div class="background-section ">
       <h3 class='t-16'> Company1 </h3>


<p class="title t-14"> JobType </p>

<div class="background-section ">
       <h3 class='t-16'> Company2 </h3>


<p class="title t-14"> JobType2 </p>
```

by trying the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(text(), 'JobType')]")
```

I still need to extract "Company1" text too but I could not relate

I want the output to find "Company1" related to JobType

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xpath` here as it is used to identify and navigate nodes in HTML.
Try below code and let me know if it works for you :-

```
Mytext = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(text(),'JobType')]/parent::div/h3").text
```

The output will be -[image]